# Open cmd.exe from JAVA with PATH Presets

Tags: java, cmd, environment

I want to open my cmd.exe by a click on a Button and with a String path that I give to my cmd.exe as a parameter (open the cmd with that path set)

```
String path = getCurrentFolderName().toString();   
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder();   
b.environment().put("PATH", path);    
b.command("cmd", "/c", "start", path)               
b.start();
```

this so far opens only the folder in a new window in Windows... how can I open my cmd.exe and pass a path to it?

Comment: Consider using `Desktop` if possible http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Answer (score 1):

Few changes necessary

- Use [`ProcessBuilder#directory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29)
- Use `/k` flag to maintain CMD shell
- Can remove final `path` argument

Result

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder();
b.directory(new File(path));
b.command("cmd", "/k", "start");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I need to do something like this I would create and delete batch files.
Use PrintWriter to create your .bat file, you can add in whatever variables you need at this point

Then to run the .bat

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

and delete it afterwords if its not needed.

Maybe not elegant, but it worked well for me before.